# How to get follower count of any instagram account?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Need the follower count of any Instagram account – best way with Graph API but cannot find anything. Only for business profiles. Don't want to use cURL since it just don't work correct and it's based on their HTML. Their old API is deprecated since June 2020.

Is it just me or is there nothing I can use?!

Comment: Try https://www.instagram.com/apple/?__a=1 and then look for `edge_followed_by`